# Prevent exiting the application being tested when using Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I've implemented some algorithm for Monkeyrunner to generate random events on an application being tested, but these random events sometimes trigger the application to exit, making the following events meaningless in the test. Is there a way to prevent this application to exit when Monkeyrunner is generating and executing random events on it? (keep launching the same application from Monkeyrunner periodically?)

Thanks.